# Files transferred by rsync from Windows to Ubuntu cannot be found by Node.js

Tags: node.js, git, ubuntu, npm, rsync

I'm having a problem with synchronizing code from my development environment on Windows with the Linux server. I am using rsync with git bash. I'm running the following commands in a while loop:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -p $SSH_PORT" "$SOURCE/" "$DESTINATION"
sleep 5
```

SSH_PORT, SOURCE and DESTINATION are variables I set earlier.
In SOURCE, I have files `index.js` (empty outside of a `console.log('a')` command)and `package.json`.
`package.json` has the following content:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {

  }
}
```

The files in SOURCE seem to be transferred correctly to my server, and can be seen with the `ls` command, but running `npm run start` gives the error `Cannot find module '/root/server/index.js'`.

I reinstalled npm and Node.js multiple times, the permissions&encoding are set correctly. If I copy and paste the files into another directory, Node.js works fine. Is there anything I can do to fix this?